# Create a button in qualtrics

Tags: html, css, qualtrics

I have a survey that I am creating, but it may be difficult to complete if the respondents do not have additional information about the topic.

I would like to create a button to redirect the respondents to a specific pdf for more information.

I can very easily have them click the link. But a button would be more professional and pleasing to the eye.

Here is the link: http://sfrc.ufl.edu/Extension/FFSnl/FL_Land_Steward_5.1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the help you guys, these codes work great.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your question text (in HTML mode):

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://sfrc.ufl.edu/Extension/FFSnl/FL_Land_Steward_5.1.pdf');">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to the HTML view of your question or "Source View" of the [Rich Content Editor](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/rich-content-editor/rich-content-editor-overview/) (You may consider making a new descriptive text question for the button alone). It essentially is a link that opens the PDF in a new tab but looks like a button.

```
<a href="http://sfrc.ufl.edu/Extension/FFSnl/FL_Land_Steward_5.1.pdf" target="blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><div style="display:block; background: #0077CC; padding: 8px 15px; border-radius:3px; color: #fff; width:95px; font-family: sans-serif; text-align: center">View PDF</div></a>
```

[What the button would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlLUZ.png)

You can edit the style attributes to change the background color, font color, or whatever else you want to change.